# finding the basis of a quotient space of A-submodules

Tags: matrices, representation-theory

Let $A$ be an associative algebra over a field $K$.
If $(e_1,...,e_n)$ is a basis of a $K$-module $M$, then by the $K$-isomorphism $K^n \longrightarrow M$ given by the assignment $(\xi_i) \longmapsto \sum_{i=1}^ne_i\xi_i$, we have a bijective correspondance between the matrix representations of $A$ of degree $n$ and the linear representations of $A$ in $M$.
Explicitly, the linear representation $\rho$ corresponding to a matrix representation $a \longmapsto (\lambda_{ij}(a))$ is given by 
\begin{equation}
\displaystyle \rho(a)e_j=\sum_{i=1}^ne_i\lambda_{ij}(a), \:\: a \in A.
\end{equation}

Let $T$, $T'$ be matrix representations of degree $n$, $n'$.
Then a homomorphism from $T$ to $T'$ is a $n' \times n$ matrix $P$ satisfying $PT(a)=T'(a)P, \: (a \in A)$.

We assume that $K$ is a field. Then a $K$-module is a linear space over $K$. A linear representation $\rho$ over $K$ of a $K$-algebra $A$ is said to be of degree $n$ if its representation module $M$ is of dimension $n$ over $K$. 
Suppose that a sequence $\{0\}=M_0 \subset M_1 \subset ... \subset M_r=M$ of $A$-submodules of $M$ is given. We take a basis $(e_1,...,e_n)$ of $M$ over $K$ such that $(e_1,...,e_{m_i})$ forms a basis of $M_i$ over $K$, $(1\leq i\leq r)$.
Then the matrix representation corresponding to $\rho$ relative to the basis $(e_1,...,e_n)$ has the form

$$
\displaystyle a \to T(a)=\begin{pmatrix}
T_{11}(a) & T_{12}(a) & \cdots & T_{1r}(a) \\
& T_{22}(a) & \cdots & T_{2r}(a) \\
& & & \\
& & \ddots & \vdots \\
& & & \\
0 & & & T_{rr}(a)
\end{pmatrix}
$$

where, if we put $n_i=\dim M_i/M_{i-1}=m_i-m_{i-1}$, $T_{ij}(a)$ is a $n_i \times n_j$ matrix and $T_{ij}(a)=0$ for $i>j$.
Please, can someone tell me how can I express the basis of the quotient space $M_i/M_{i-1}$ over $K$. 
I tried to express this basis with respect to the basis $(e_1,...,e_{m_i})$ of $M_i$, but it doesn't seem to work at all.

To be more precise, I have to find the matrix representation corresponding to the linear representation $\rho_i$ associated with $M_i/M_{i-1}$ relative to this (mysterious) basis.

Any suggestion would be appreciated because I'm not used with those new concepts.

Comment: Use $(e_{m_{i-1}+1},\ldots,e_{m_i})$

Comment: Thank you very much. It works and I find $T_{ii}$ as a matrix representation for $\rho_i$.

Comment: I should have read more closely my own question to see that $n_i=\dim M_i/M_{i-1}=m_i -m_{i-1}$ !